# Get Azure IoT Hub Consumer Groups Programmatically Using C# SDK

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

Azure IoT Hub relies heavily on consumer groups. We can easily add consumer groups and view them using Azure Portal.

[image]

Is there anyway to read my consumer groups using C# SDK?

Comment: Can you use the REST APIs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource/geteventhubconsumergroup

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Take a look at this API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.iothub.iiothubresourceoperations.listeventhubconsumergroupswithhttpmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet

If you look at the available operations [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.iothub.iiothubresourceoperations?view=azure-dotnet), you can create and delete consumer groups on the default endpoint as well.